# TSQL - Get Last Successful Date

Tags: sql-server

I am struck with the below logic. Whenever the status is failed, I need to `max(EndTime)` when it was previously successful. For example in the below data, for `Batch = 3987` the `lastrefreshdate` should be `23-01-2017` but not `13-02-2017`.

Below is the snippet of the data and the query.

```
Batch   TableName   IsFullLoad  Status  EndTime     LastRefreshDate
5524    SA                 1    Loaded  13-02-2017  13-02-2017
4746    SA                 1    Loaded  06-02-2017  06-02-2017
4174    SA                 1    Loaded  31-01-2017  31-01-2017
3987    SA                 1    Failed  30-01-2017  13-02-2017
3372    SA                 1    Loaded  23-01-2017  23-01-2017
2651    SA                 1    Loaded  16-01-2017  16-01-2017
1987    SA                 1    Loaded  09-01-2017  09-01-2017
1379    SA                 1    Loaded  02-01-2017  02-01-2017
835     SA                 1    Loaded  26-12-2016  26-12-2016
189     SA                 1    Loaded  19-12-2016  19-12-2016
52      SA                 1    Loaded  17-12-2016  17-12-2016
```

SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 40*
FROM (
SELECT
bi.Id,
bi.TableName,
bi.IsFullLoad,
bi.JobId,
[Status],
bi.CompletTime,
CASE 
WHEN bi.IsFullLoad = 1 AND bi.[Status] = 'Failed' 
THEN
(
SELECT MAX(CompletTime) FROM  Audit.T1 bb
  WHERE [Status]= 'Loaded' AND bb.IsFullLoad = 1  AND bb.TableName = bi.TableName 
  GROUP BY bb.TableName
  )
 ELSE 
 bi.CompletTime 
 END AS Validto
FROM Audit.T1 bi
WHERE TableName = 'Salesforce_Account' AND bi.IsFullLoad = 1
) x 
ORDER BY x.CompletTime desc
```

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner query is selecting the last `completTime` from the table where the conditions are met, but no where in the conditions you reference the current record's `CompletTime`.

Change the inner query from this:

```
SELECT MAX(CompletTime) FROM  Audit.T1 bb
WHERE [Status]= 'Loaded' AND bb.IsFullLoad = 1  AND bb.TableName = bi.TableName 
GROUP BY bb.TableName
```

To this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CompletTime 
FROM  Audit.T1 bb
WHERE [Status]= 'Loaded' 
AND bb.IsFullLoad = 1  
AND bb.TableName = bi.TableName 
AND CompletTime < b1.CompletTime
ORDER BY CompletTime DESC
```

Of course, you can still use `MAX` - but add the relevant condition. `Group by` is not needed.

```
SELECT MAX(CompletTime)
FROM  Audit.T1 bb
WHERE [Status]= 'Loaded' 
AND bb.IsFullLoad = 1  
AND bb.TableName = bi.TableName 
AND CompletTime < b1.CompletTime
```